# SQL aliases not working anymore after migrating from Hibernate 3 to 4

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am migrating a Struts2 Web Application from Hibernate V3 to Hibernate 4.3.5.

In Hibernate V3 we used SQL statements like the following, and **they worked well** :

```
select u.id as id, 
       u.userId as userId, 
       sum(u.totalSearchedFields) as total, 
       u.date as date, 
       u.status as status 
from user u;
```

After migrating to Hibernate V4.3.5, the above SQL statement shows the error:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: `, expected in SELECT`

We made it work by removing the aliases from the SQL statement, like this:

```
select u.id, 
       u.userId, 
       sum(u.totalSearchedFields), 
       u.date, 
       u.status 
from user u;
```

Does anyone recognize the cause for this? How to fix this problem without removing the aliases?

Comment: I'm not sure why this happens but Hibernate V4 seems to be more strict than Hibernate V3 (e.g. V3 silently accepted things like `where x = null`, V4 will throw an exception) so you might experience the same thing. IMHO aliases in selects aren't that useful anyways since you can't address them in the query and Hibernate would not make use of them when building the entities or result lists.

Comment: Maybe some alias you used is now considered a reserved word (for example `total`, or `date`). Try run the first query by changing aliases names, for example by appending `_FOO` at the end of each alias

Comment: `date` and `user` are a reserved keywords. You shouldn't be using those. Also check other aliases and names.

Comment: @AndreaLigios, Thanks for editing my question. Now it seems better.

Comment: Its not an actual SQL query, i replaced all columns from the actual SQL query. eg. I replaced u.date instead of u.lastModifiedDate..

Comment: So maybe you need to show actual query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appearently, according to the [Hibernate 4 developer guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch13.html#d5e3754), the aliases should be used in an "inversed" way from what you did before:

```
SELECT <PROPERTY_NAME> AS <ALIAS_TABLE.PROPERTY_NAME> 
  FROM TABLE AS <ALIAS_TABLE>
```

So try changing this:

```
select u.id as id, 
       u.userId as userId, 
       sum(u.totalSearchedFields) as total, 
       u.date as date, 
       u.status as status 
from user u;
```

to this:

```
select id as {u.id},
       userId as {u.userId}, 
       sum(totalSearchedFields) as total, 
       date as {u.date}, 
       status as {u.status}
from user u;
```

The approach seems a bit different from the SQL's one, because this aliases are intended to be used by Hibernate to prevent multiple columns with the same name to conflict, while in SQL they were used to generate an user-friendly ResultSet.

A long shot BTW, hope that helps.